# How to assign a command or callback to a tkinter listbox

Tags: python, tkinter

I have found that almost all of tkinter's widgets have some way of adding a callback or command function to them that will be called whenever the widget is clicked. I cannot seem to find a way of doing this for a listbox.
Is there any way of adding a callback to a listbox?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you can bind `<<ListboxSelect>>` to the list box.

```
listbox = tk.Listbox(root)
listbox.bind("<<ListboxSelect>>", callback)
```

Comment: Thank you. This worked. @abccd

Comment: Do I need to put something other than ` "<<ListboxSelect>>" ` in there?

Comment: Not for this, you only need to bind "<<ListboxSelect>>", you can check the manual for more details https://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl8.4/TkCmd/listbox.htm#M60 and here are more events and bindings you can check out http://effbot.org/tkinterbook/tkinter-events-and-bindings.htm Note: <<ListboxSelect>> is a unique binding that only works on listboxs

Comment: As stated in the above doc, *Any time the selection changes in the listbox, the virtual event <<ListboxSelect>> will be generated. It is easiest to bind to this event to be made aware of any changes to listbox selection.* which this basically the "command" argument for listboxs